# Python compare filename with folder name

Tags: python, operating-system, compare

I just start python and i have to compare filename with folder name to launch the good sh script. (i'm using airflow)

```
import glob
import os
import shutil
from os import path

odsPath = '/apps/data/02_ODS/'
receiptPath = '/apps/data/80_DATA/01_Receipt/'


for files in os.listdir(receiptPath):
    if(files.startswith('MEM_ZMII') or files.startswith('FMS') and files.endswith('.csv')):
        parsedFiles = files.split('_')
        pattern = '_'.join(parsedFiles[0:2])
        fileName = '_'.join(parsedFiles[2:5])
        fileName = fileName.split('-')[0].lower()
        # print('appCode: ', pattern)
        # print('fileName: ', fileName)


for odsFolder in os.listdir(odsPath):
    if(odsFolder == fileName):
        print('it exist: ', str(fileName))
    else:
        print('it\'s not')
```

I got 3 files in receiptPath , it only matching for 1 file, but not the others. Can someone help me?

Thank a lot!

Comment: So whats your problem??

Comment: i've 3 files suppose to match with the folder name, but it only match for one, why not for the others?

Comment: Maybe you could give us the name of files so we can test your script and see

Comment: It looks like you’re overwriting your values. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, your problem is that you overwrite your variable `fileName`, so at the end of the first for loop, it only keeps the last value, which is `material_makt`. The solution consists in saving all the filenames in a list `fileNames_list`, and then you can check `if (odsFolder in fileNames_list)` :

```
import glob
import os
import shutil
from os import path

odsPath = '/apps/data/02_ODS/'
receiptPath = '/apps/data/80_DATA/01_Receipt/'


fileNames_list = []
for files in os.listdir(receiptPath):
    if(files.startswith('MEM_ZMII') or files.startswith('FMS') and files.endswith('.csv')):
        parsedFiles = files.split('_')
        pattern = '_'.join(parsedFiles[0:2])
        fileName = '_'.join(parsedFiles[2:5])
        fileName = fileName.split('-')[0].lower()
        fileNames_list.append(fileName)

for odsFolder in os.listdir(odsPath):
    if (odsFolder in fileNames_list):
        print('it exist:', str(odsFolder))
    else:
        print('it\'s not')
```

Output :

```
it exist: zcormm_familymc
it exist: kpi_obj_data
it exist: material_makt
```